# internet explorer 6 php serve file problem

Tags: php, download, header, internet-explorer-6

hail, i have a problem to serve file with PHP into client. that when i want to download it the save and open dialog will be appear but progress of download will not show. what is my problem?

header that i send it to client:

```
header('Content-Type: ');
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
```

**save dialog**

http ://vzz.ir/files/kn5gsecfnoia1cqkfop6.jpg

**progress not show in ip.**

http ://vzz.ir/files/88ruak7ocjgn10ha9mda.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set header with file size to make progress bar appear. Content-type also should be specified, use **application/ocet-stream** for unknown mime type (or to force download).

```
header('Content-Type: application/ocet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.dat');
header('Content-Length: '.filesize('test.dat'));
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
readfile('test.dat');
exit;
```

Comment: both of theme is affected but progress problem is still. :(